# session file - when does it get created exactly?

Tags: php, session, global-variables

I'm curious to know exactly when the session text file is created? An easy and surface level answer to that would probably be,.. well, when you use session_start().  But is it?
Could it be all the way at the end when the php script ends?

What makes me think that it may be at the end is that I know PHP would not write to the session file everytime you make a change to a session variables while the execution of the page goes on. For example, if you got something like `$_SESSION['x'] = $_SESSION['x'] + 1;` in a loop, the session file does **NOT** get modified at each and every iteration of the loop. Only when the PHP scripts is done, then the PHP engine makes a change into the file, to store the final value of the `$_SESSION['x']`.

With the same taken of logic, I see no reason for PHP engine to create a file as soon as you call the session_start. It could just delay the process.

What that entails is this;

I can start a session with `session_start()`, set a few session variables, toss them around within functions, using them as globals, and at the end of script, I unset them, and destroy the session and as a result, I assume NO SESSION FILE IS CREATED, thus no overhead associated with creating the session text files is experienced.

I would like to hear your insights in this.

My purpose is to explore the possibilities of using session variables strictly as a temporary place holder to pass global variables left and right - without dealing with file I/O. In fact, I do not need those variables in the next page at all.

In this case, could sessions prove faster than using globals within functions?

Comment: Creating Global Scope deliberately is a Very Bad Thing. The theoretical part of your question is interesting nevertheless.

Comment: php doesn't necessarily write files. you can call session_set_save_handler and supply your own persistence function. you could try writing your own implementation and just note when it is called (likely on session_write_close() or at the end of your script execution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested and it gets created *immediately* on `session_start`.  However, `session_destroy` removes it too.  Tested with:

```
mkdir sess && cd sess
vim main.php

session_save_path(dirname(__FILE__));
session_start();
sleep(5);
session_destroy();

php main.php &
ls # main.php   sess_rm4bcun6ear943mf61mdads190
fg # wait for script to end
ls # main.php
```

There's the answer to your question.  Your idea of using `_SESSION` for global variable purposes is not a good one .. you might as well juse use `$GLOBALS`.  No file IO there.